# Bootstrap control changes position height based on width of screen

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a bootstrap row containing a header tag and a link tag. They are aligned on the same row when the screen width is less than 768 pixels. When the container width is 768 or greater the link element shifts a few pixels higher.

Here is an example that demonstrates this behaviour: https://jsfiddle.net/bz3399x8/

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-12">
    <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#" style="width: 80px; float: right;">
      <i class="icon-plus">
        Add
      </i>
    </a>
    <h1>
      Hello World
    </h1> 
  </div>
</div>
```

Here are screenshots demonstrating this behaviour.

There are two issues:

1. what is causing this?
2. how to i fix this?

[image: container width: 767px]
[image: container width: 768px - changed height position of link element]

Comment: It's your col-sm-12. On screen sizes larger than 768, it floats left, which increases the height of the container. If you change it to col-md-12, or something larger, you'll notice the breakpoint changes from 768 to 906 or something close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your syntax according to [Bootstrap Docs](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) is wrong,

- it needs the `.container` to wrap `.row`

and

- `h1` and `a` button elements needs to  be wrapped in Bootstrap columns.
  So, you can use `.col-sm-10` + `.col-sm-2` in this case.

Added `.col-xs` for demo

```css
.row {
  /* demo*/
  background:red
}
.btn  {
  margin-top:20px /* choose as it fit you better */
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-10 col-sm-10">
      <h1>
      Hello World
    </h1>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2">
      <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#">
        <i class="icon-plus">
        Add
      </i>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This worked best for my actual problem as it was truly responsive for mobile devices (including iPhone4 dimensions)

Comment: I found that changing the main col from sm to xs (col-xs-12) had the best responsive mobile layout while still keeping the html and class tags simple

Comment: @Coderama If you check the docs you'll see that you can use all the classes in one HTML tag depending on what kind of design you want :)

Answer (score 1):

While wrapping elements in different column will help answer your problem. If you are looking at wrapping both elements inside single column you need to specify elements to be inline. Problem is occurring since `h1` element and `a` element even though in same row for bootstrap but are displayed as `block` and `inline-block`.

Add `display: inline-block` to `h1` element with top padding to `a` element. This should answer it as well.

Try it with `display: inline` on `h1` see the difference in behavior. `inline` element dont support vertical margins.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dk_dragonknight/m8ey6mba/